# security/crypto: encrypting TCP message using zeroMQ

Tags: security, tcp, cryptography, zeromq

I'm a security/crypto newbie looking for some advice on whether my system is secure, and if not, whether crypto is the right answer for me. Here's my situation:

- I am sending TCP messages via zeroMQ req/rep between remote servers
- The system has a fixed number N senders, and 1 receiver
- I am not *TOO* worried about others reading my message (although preferably not), but I absolutely do not want others to be able to masquerade as one of my senders, as the messages contain instructions for the receiver to execute
- Latency/performance is a large factor. I expect 100k+ messages/second to be sent

Ideally, is there a way for me, since I know who are the authorized senders, to specify on my receiver to only accept messages from so-and-so and be safe knowing that? Either in zeromq itself or other method?

Thanks all for your help!

Comment: I think zeromq 4.0 has added crypto based on CurveCP. But I'm not sure if it fits your requirements

Answer (score 0):

If you share an AES key between all your senders (preferable via SSH or reliable other public key infrastructure) you would be quite safe. The receiver doesn't have to know exactly which system that sent the request, it's the same key all over.

BUT: since you are sending a lot of packets that all are small you HAVE TO make sure you pad your data in a clever way (likely with transaction id that you have a counting check for on the receiver's end, sender id + some random data). If you don't, you will be open for [replaying attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Replay_attack), whether the malicious person has the key or not.

Another fun interesting approach is to send [challenge-responses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Challenge%E2%80%93response_authentication) from the receiver somehow, i. e. a random number that is hashed together with some common key (which one of them should be considered the "[salt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_%28cryptography%29)"?). And please, do not the symmetric encryption key for this, please - if someone manages to attack the challenge/response somehow you will also give them your holy shared key.

A response with the made hashing, the "answer" to the challenge, proves that the senders have the same secret key as the receiver / challenger have, and can be quite quick (SHA-1 or similar are fast).

Have fun. Don't you never, ever dare to use your solution for real.